# Login/Logout field in menu bar is out of place and not functioning (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, authentication, menu, logout

The past two days I have been trying to learn how to add a nice login/logout/register field into the top menu bar of my site. I just recently began familiarizing myself with editor. I dug this code up here in stackoverflow. I like the way it looks and I'm hoping to tweek it a bit.

```
    /* Custom Login Menu Field */
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);

function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
// start buffering
ob_start();
// this is the actual form function
wp_login_form($args); // $args optional see below ..
// get buffering
$loginoutform = ob_get_contents();
// clean buffering
ob_end_clean();
$items .= $loginoutform ; // concatenate buffering with items ...
return $items;
}
```

What I would like to do is have the login field area centered horizontally in the middle of the top/main menu bar. As you can see it is currently all the way to the right and stretches out the whole thing. When I use it- it does log me in, but does not switch to a "logout" option when signed in.

If anyone has any knowledge in this area on how I could add or modify my starter code I would be very grateful. Best regards- Cypher.

Site: cypherbeats.com
Theme: Jarvis (latest)
Code was added into functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At time of writing I cannot see this login bar you speak of. So cannot say whether your code works.

In your code you can use the function `is_user_logged_in()` as a conditional to check whether the visitor is logged in. Therefore you can use it to decide whether to output the login or logout code. The `wp_loginout()` function appears to display a logout button. So something like this coud work:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);

function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
// start buffering
ob_start();
// this is the actual form function
if( !is_user_logged_in() )
    wp_login_form($args); // $args optional see below ..
else
    wp_loginout();
// get buffering
$loginoutform = ob_get_contents();
// clean buffering
ob_end_clean();
$items .= $loginoutform ; // concatenate buffering with items ...
return $items;
}
```

**Warning** I haven't tested this and is just a suggestion to start you off.

Here is an alternative approach that might be handy. First install this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/ Then create a login link which is only visible to logged out users and a logout link that is only visible to logged in users. You could then write some javascript which causes the login form to popup in a lightbox when you press the login button. I use this approach at https://ptofchoice.com.au/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do appreciate you taking the time to help me out. And sorry for that not being there during the time you went to check I added some code on my own and caused a fatal error throughout my entire wordpress and had to restore a backup.. lol. I'm going to give your information a shot and will respond very soon with the results.

Comment: The switch to show log out did work :) Again menu becomes stretched down to show the form, and after logging in the logout option throws itself next to my "support" menu option. Sadly I'm not knowledgeable enough to glue this idea together into a polished working function. I did check out your site and have to say I'm liking the look of it. Definitely would be the better approach for me but I'm stubborn and don't want to give up on this. - Also, I'm going to leave this login code in for now so you can take a second look at what's going on.

Comment: Basically you are trying to make the login part of the menu. Since you're positioning the login form in the centre it might be easier to output in the code where you produce the header. Making the form look nice is really a separate problem to getting it to work

Comment: Yes, Don't think I really mind how good it looks for now ^-^ My header.php didn't produce anything so I tried my menu_section.php just messing around and the code placed itself written out in the middle of the menu when I refreshed homepage (embarrassed) But at least it gave me the hint. I would like to show you my menu_section code to see if you could find a suitable place for me to add in my login code. Can I paste it into comment here?

Comment: I'd suggest you'd be better off making a new question and post a link. Your login form is not going to be part of the menu. I'd strongly advise not to shoehorn it into any menu code

Comment: Thanks for the marked answer! When you post another question be sure to include some header.php code. I need to go to bed though so won't be able to attack it for about 10 hours

Comment: Hey no problem. I'm very grateful for your help. It's been tough wrapping my head around everything so someone taking the time out to help me learn is awesome. Here is the continued post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578323/add-user-login-fields-form-in-existing-menu